# link rel import not working in Mozila Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have one issue.I want to call HTML file like the following way.But its only working in Google chrome.In Mozila Firefox its not working at all.

```
<link rel="import" href="controllerHTML/adminController.html">
```

> adminController.html:

```
<script src="../controller/loginController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../controller/adminController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../controller/adminCollegeProfileController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../controller/adminResController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../controller/adminResourceUserRoleController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../controller/adminResourceClassController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here my requirement is i need to call this `adminController.html`   file in body part of my index.html.This `adminController.html` file contains some js links which are including dynamically.But its only working in Chrome.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using any framework like AngularJS or libraries such as jQuery? Or are you seeking for a solution in vanilla JS?

Comment: @FelisCatus : I am using angular.js .As i have so many controller file i dont want to include all in index page.I want to call those by keeping in another page.

Comment: In that case it's better to open another question with focus on angular controllers dynamic loading and stuff like that, since that would be a completely different topic. Let's keep the discussion on HTML import here.

Comment: Ok,I will focus another question.

Answer (score 0):

HTML import is still [relatively new technology in W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/). It may take some time before they are adopted by browsers.

As of Nov 2015, HTML import is enabled by default in Chrome, but only available behind a flag in Firefox. Please check [the support table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=imports) for more details and relevant issues.

Comment: @ FelisCatus : Ok,I have already read this table.Its good to avoid this way for now.Can you Please suggest me what is the best way to include js links dynamically.I am updating `adminController.html` file in my post.

Comment: Please check my post .

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has [no intentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) to support imports in the future due to their focus on Web Components:

> Firefox will not ship HTML Imports. See [this Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/mozilla-and-web-components/) for more information. You can still use HTML Imports in Firefox by enabling the dom.webcomponents.enabled flag. If you don't want to enable the flag, you can use a polyfill such as Google's webcomponents.js.

As they propose, you can use [Google's webcomponents.js](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills) instead:

> Some browsers are still in the process of updating to support the standards for Web Components. In the mean time, polyfills simulate the missing browser capabilities as closely as possible.